# Link between probability space and random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose $\Omega=\{A,B\}$, $\mathcal{F}$ consists of all possible subsets, $P\{A\}=P\{B\}=\frac{1}{2}$, $X(A)=-1$ and $X(B)=1$. Write the expression of $\mu_X(\mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is any Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it correct that when $-1 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $1 \in \mathcal{B}$, $\mu_X(\mathcal{B})=1$? If not, I wonder where I made a mistake. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu_X(\mathcal{B})=P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\in \mathcal{B}\})=\begin{cases}0,&-1,1\not\in\mathcal{B} \\
P(B)=1/2,&-1\not\in\mathcal{B}, 1\in\mathcal{B}\\
P(A)=1/2,&1\not\in\mathcal{B},-1\in\mathcal{B}\\
P(A\cup B)=1,&-1,1\in\mathcal{B}\end{cases}$